# What is the maximum weight a micro 4/3 lens mount can support without a tripod collar?

Tags: lens-mount, micro-four-thirds, weight

What maximum weight one can expect the micro 4/3 lens mount to hold without breaking (for a lens with no tripod collar)?

Are there official specifications about this?

Comment: The particularity of this question is linked to the lightweight nature of m4/3 bodies.

Comment: And also falls under the broader umbrella of the other question and the answers to it, which would include m4/3 bodies. With a lighter camera body you're going to need to support the lens as opposed to the camera even sooner to maintain proper balance and handling. Thus you will be supporting the lens, rather than the camera, even earlier before you reach the load limits of the mount design.

Comment: Now that's interesting. According to you the mount would then support more that can possibly be supported hand-held from the body.

Comment: No, that's not what I said. What I said is that the mount will support more mass than that with which you can "maintain proper balance and handling." Anytime the lens puts more load on the connecting flange than the body it is time to start supporting the camera/lens combo primarily via the lens. The mounting flanges are built to handle more load than that. Otherwise they'd break in two every time a camera is dropped from more than a few inches.